# How to add submenu to dataview of Ext.menu.Menu in extjs4

Tags: menu, extjs4, dataview

i am working in extjs4. I have Ext.menu.Menu with dataview as item. I have code for this as=

```
var projectTpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
                    '<tpl for=".">',
                        '<table id="table" class="project">' ,
                            '<tr width=\"100%\">',
                                '<tpl>' ,
                                    '<td><img id="img"></td>',                      
                                '</tpl>',
                                '<td style="line-height: 150%; padding-left: 5px;">' ,
                                    '<span class="fileName"><span style = "font-weight: bold;">{projectId}</span>',
                                    '<span class="username" style="color: #707070; font-family: VegurMedium,sans-serif; font-size: 12px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;Approved the file<b> {projectName} </span> '+
                                '</td>',
                            '</tr>',
                        '</table>',
                    '</tpl>');  


         var detailsMenu =  Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu',{
            items: [{
                xtype: 'dataview',
                autoScroll: true,
                height: 250,
                width : 400,
                store : 'ProjectStore',
                tpl:projectTpl
            }]
        });
```

I want to create submenu as "Send Email" to each of datview's item. So how to add such submenu to dataview of 'Ext.menu.menu' in extjs4